# OpenShift Online Starter oc cli authentication

Tags: openshift

When I log in with openshift online starter oc cli version 3.6.0, the openshift username and the github.com password are asked, I don't understand how authentication is done without having entered the github.com username.

Comment: If you are sill using `oc` client version 3.6 you should upgrade it for a start. OpenShift Online is likely 3.11 at this point and you should use the matching major/minor version, or at least, only one minor version different.

Comment: OpenShift Online uses Keycloak authentication. With Keycloak (specifically developers.redhat.com), it has social integration enabled. This allows you to create a Keycloak account, but use something like Github to login (it's linked to your Keycloak account, which is how Keycloak knows that Github account matches to that Keycloak account). So your "OpenShift account" is just an account on Keycloak, but then it uses the Github password to login.

Comment: My Keycloak account is linked to my github.com account so it knows my github.com username and I can login with Keycloak username and github.com password, is it right?